# Upgrading to PipeWire: pipewire-session-manager.service already exists and is a symlink to /usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-media-session.service

Tags: debian, pipewire

From the [Debian Testing Unstable wiki on upgrading to PipeWire](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire#Debian_Testing.2FUnstable) when I run

```bash
systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service
```

I get,

> Failed to enable unit: File ~/.config/systemd/user/pipewire-session-manager.service already exists and is a symlink to /usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-media-session.service.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `--force` option

```
systemctl --force --user --now enable wireplumber.service
```